# how to stop error emails arriving from symfony

Tags: symfony

[image de monolog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J9IW.jpg)I have a problem which is that I cannot block the error emails that arrive via symfony and I receive too many messages. Who can help me? here is the monolog file.

I was going to try to remove the whole 'symfony mailer' part but I didn't dare because I think it has a relationship with sending other types of emails

Comment: Can you please add the relevant log entries to your question!

Comment: I supposed you have something like monolog bundle activated, so you just need to change the mail system by file or stream one

Comment: now i added the image of my monolog file

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved